# WxPython Always On Top window

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a window in wxPython, that not only always shows on top all other windows, but also sticks to the top edge of the screen. But if something's already there (like Gnome Dash, or XFCE panel), my own panel doesn't cover it, but shows up beneath it.

I'm using

```
wx.STAY_ON_TOP
```

and either

```
pos=(0, 0)
```

or

```
self.SetPosition(wx.Point(0, 0))
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Normal windows are limited to the "client area" of the screen, i.e. beneath the panel (or taskbar under MSW), so you're simply out of luck.

Comment: Does your answer imply that it is possible to use some window that is not "normal" to solve this problem?

Comment: No, not really. There are various platform-specific ways to add contents to the panels (e.g. "applets" in Gnome) or even define new bars, but you can't just have a window overlapping them. Besides, I have no idea why would you want it to, perhaps you need to use `wxNotificationMessage` instead?

Comment: As far as I understand, there's no way to remove the title bar and borders in wxNotificationMessage. And I also need to be able to change the contents of my window periodically, so that's a no go. Perhaps, placing it beneath the panel (or above it, if it's located on the bottom of the screen) would be ok, but right now, if I set it's position to (0, 0) get's hidden below the XFCE panel. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Position (0, 0) _should_ be just below the XFCE panel. Unfortunately it's not impossible that there is a bug in client area computation in wxGTK code, it's hard to support all the different Linux DE/WMs, quite of which are broken in their own special ways...

Comment: I had to use wx.Display().GetClientArea()[1] for the Y position of my frame, for it to be properly placed under the panel, and also add the same value to my frame's height, as it was also cropped to the height of the panel by default. Probably another bug.